# DEG monobutyl ether pH change

Tags: organic-chemistry, ph, solvents, ethers

We are using DEG monobutyl ether (CAS 112-34-5) in our production. Normally it is pH neutral, however suddenly we noticed that it has shifted to being acidic (pH=3.4).

What has changed in the material? I have not been able to identify any decomposition that might have taken place, so the question is if the material is still usable?

pH changes can be caused by minimal changes in the material, however I am out of office and not really able to verify it right now.

Comment: That's a pretty large change. Are you confident in your pH measuring system?

Comment: Yes, 100%, confirmed via calibrated digital meter several times + pH strips....

Comment: Ethers are known to pick up oxygen and become peroxides. Light and access to air accentuate the process. The presence of transition metals can catalyze various oxidations. The unetherified hydroxylic carbon  probably goes to an acid. Whether it's usable depends on your process. Perhaps you could run it thru a bed of limestone to adsorb out the acid.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @JamesGaidis, we changed the container we store it in recently, the new container is not 100% airtight, so that's the answer....

Comment: @Michal: an extensive reference (10 pp) is at http://ccc.chem.pitt.edu/wipf/Web/16340.pdf   But it is scary! But if you keep the air out, you should be OK. Maybe you can add an inhibitor - or maybe your process actually uses the peroxide in some way...